# qml: ExclusiveGroup is not a type

Tags: qml

I import QtQuick.Controls 2.15, to use ExclusiveGroup QML Type, but the error occur! saying "ExclusiveGroup is not a type", is there anyone know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-exclusivegroup.html) for the ExclusiveGroup QML Type the correct import statement is

`import QtQuick.Controls 1.4`

Answer (score 1):

I recommend avoiding QtQuick.Controls 1, and moving to QtQuick.Controls 2, if you can. There is no ExclusiveGroup in v2, but there is something called [ButtonGroup](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-buttongroup.html) that should do what you want.

Comment: Great suggestion, completely forgot about ButtonGroup